# While loop going infinitely because of a class method that returns wrong values - Python

Tags: python, oop, while-loop

I'm just playing around with python concepts such as while loops, classes, methods and return values. The thing is, to make it "more attractive" I'm doing it with a class that's named `Pokemon()`. The code looks like this

```py
import random

class Pokemon():
    def __init__(self): #Pokemon atrributes
        self.health = 100
        self.damage = 5
        self.__lives = 3 #? //Not used
    
    def checkalive(self, opponent): #Check if the pokemon's still alive, args: the pokemon and the opponent
        while self.health and opponent.health > 0: 
            return True #If both of them alive, return true
            break
        
        return False #If neither of them  alive, return false

    def attack(self, opponent): #Attack function, args: the pokemon and the opponent
        
        while True:
            check = self.checkalive(opponent) #Check if the pokemons are alive
            while check == True: #In case it returns True go on with the combat
                randomNumber = random.randint(0,5) #Just creating a random number
                if randomNumber == 3: #If that random number equals to 3 (20%) the opponent will defend itself and will contraatack our Pokemon
                    self.health -= opponent.damage
                    print("Got it wrong! You've got " + str(self.health)  + " HP remaining.")
                    
                else: #If not (80%), just go on with the combat
                    opponent.health -= self.damage
                    print("The opponent now has " + str(opponent.health) + " HP! Your pokemon still has got " + str(self.health) + " HP left.")
                    
            
            print("End of combat") #Once one of them is dead, end of combat
            break


Squirtle = Pokemon() #Our pokemon
Pikachu = Pokemon() #Opponent
Squirtle.attack(Pikachu)
```

I've created two very basic methods. One is `checkalive()`, just as its name says it just makes sure if the Pokemons involved in a combat are still alive, returning True or False values.

The other one is `attack()`, that basically just hurts the Ally Pokemon/Opponent Pokemon depending on a probability of 80%/20%. It is a really simple code and before implementing the checkalive() function it worked perfectly. However, now the while runs an indeterminately ammount of times, going below negative health values. I tried to figure what's going on, tried to change the "While" for an "If" condition statement and etc, but still no clue. Any suggestion would be really appreciated.
[image: Output console]

Comment: `while self.health and opponent.health > 0` This does **not** check if both values are greater than zero.  It checks if `self.health` is **any nonzero value**, which is probably not what you meant...

Comment: Perhaps you meant `while self.health > 0 and opponent.health > 0` instead.

Comment: Although I've already found my mistake was that I wasn't updating the loop condition, I see also that what you said is true, I'm going to check it out and apply it, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are forgetting to update the loop condition! Notice that `check` is never updated in your while loop. What you have to do is the following:

```py
while check == True:
    ... # do whatever you would like to do like generate random number etc.
    check = self.checkalive(opponent)
```

This should work.

Comment: Thanks! I was so focused on other things that I forgot the most important one, this works for me!

Answer (score 1):

it goes on because you don't change the variable check in while loop. Working while loop would look like this:

```
while check:
    # some code
    check = self.checkalive(opponent)
```

you can also change checkalive() to this:

```
def checkalive(self, opponent):
    return self.health > 0 and opponent.health > 0
```

hope it helped